# Позиция элемента в отсортированном массиве

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив:

```
var arr = ['3','12','43','55','63','90'];
```

И есть какое-то число, допустим **13**.

Требуется найти такой индекс в массиве, чтобы элемент, на который он ссылается, был наибольшим из существующих элементов, которые меньше или равны заданному.

К примеру:
**13** больше **12** (`arr[1]`), но меньше **43** (`arr[2]`), значит метод должен вернуть индекс **1** (`вторая позиция`)
Какими путями это можно реализовать?

Comment: Массив отсортированный?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, да

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 Ну цикл-то Вы можете написать?

Comment: @Igor, попытки тщетны.. arr.each(function(i){ if((num >= i) && (num <= i+1)) return i; }); // где arr - массив, а num - "13".

Comment: Посчитать количество значений <= искомому. Или нет такой функции?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собственно, если Ваш массив отсортированный, то Вам поможет старый добрый `бинарный поиск`, реализованный следующим образом:

```js
function binSearch(arr, toFind) {
  if (!arr) return -1;
  var first = 0;
  var last = arr.length - 1;
  while (first < last) {
    var mid = first + Math.floor((last - first) / 2);
    if (arr[mid] >= toFind) last = mid;
    else first = mid + 1;
  }
  if (arr[last] == toFind || last == 0 || last == arr.length - 1)
    return last;
  else
    return last - 1;
}

console.log(binSearch(['3', '12', '43', '55', '63', '90'], 13)); // 1
```

Надеюсь, ответ помог Вам, удачи в Ваших делах!

Comment: если в данном массиве искать не 13 а 93, то получим результат 5, а надо 6.

Comment: @teran 5 и надо. В массиве 6 элементов. Откуда Вы взяли 6-ой индекс, товарищ?)

Comment: а если 62, то получим 3, а должны 4.

Comment: Товарищ, остановитесь! Ещё раз вчитайтесь вопрос, а также вспомните, что отсчёт мы начинаем с нуля) Так что алгоритм выдаёт именно то, что нужно)

Comment: ниоткуда не взял, но вставить надо в конец, расширив массив, очевидно, т.к. все элементы массива меньше искомого. При этом последний элемент станет предполседним, а не оборот. вставив на 5ю позицию, вы нарушите сортировку массива

Comment: @teran Вчитайтесь в задание) Я лишь представил код, который исполняет ровно то, что было нужно товарищу спрашивающему)

Comment: с нуля с нуля. вы предлагаете вставку 62, как `3,12,43,62,55`, я же говорю что вставить надо как `3,12,43,55,62`

Comment: @teran В задании нет ничего о вставке, так бы я с Вами безусловно согласился) ТС просит найти такой индекс, элемент по которому является наибольшим из тех, которые меньше или равны заданному

Comment: оу, вчитался. вставлять не надо, надо заменить. пардоньте, пойти спать пора :D

Comment: @teran Ничего, бывает) Отдыхайте, доброй Вам ночи)